# Using extremely small floats in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Python 3 and trying to plot the half-life time of a process. The formula for this half life time is -ln(2)/(ln(1-f)). In this formula, f is an extremely small number, of the order 10^-17 most of the time, and even less.

Because I have to plot a range of values of f, I have to repeat the calculation -ln(2)/(ln(1-f)) multiple times. I do this via the expression

```
np.log(2)/(-1*np.log(1-f))
```

When I plot the half life time for many values of f, I find that for really small values of f, Python starts rounding 1-f to the same number, even though I input the same values of f.

Is there anyway I could increase float precision so that Python could distuingish between outputs of 1-f for small changes in f?

Comment: Be more precise about python vs. numpy. numpy only supports [those types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.types.html). Within python, one could use [decimals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html). I hope the general characteristics of fp-math are clear to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you want can be achieved using [`numpy.log1p`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html). It computes `log(1 + x)` with a better numerical precision than `numpy.log(1 + x)`, or, as the docs say:

> For real-valued input, `log1p` is accurate also for `x` so small that 
>   `1 + x == 1` in floating-point accuracy.

With this your code becomes:

```
import numpy as np

min_f, max_f = -32, -15
f = np.logspace(min_f, max_f, max_f - min_f + 1)
y = np.log(2)/(-1*np.log1p(-f))
```

This can be evaluated consistently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.loglog(f, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This function will only stop working if your values of `f` leave the range of floats, i.e. down to `1e-308`. This should be sufficient for any physical measurement (especially considering that there is such a thing as a smallest physical time-scale, the [Planck-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) t_P = 5.39116(13)e-44 s).